# Access VBA creating unqualified reference while looping through excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through Excel sheets in Access and keep ending up with an unqualified reference to excel.

```
Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExcelWorkbook As Workbook
Dim ExcelWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim salesfile As String

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

salesfile = "C:\filename"

Set ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(salesfile)

With ExcelApp
  With ExcelWorkbook
    For Each ExcelWorkSheet In .Worksheets

     i = i + 1

    Next ExcelWorkSheet
  End With
End With

ExcelWorkbook.Save
ExcelWorkbook.Close
Set ExcelWorkSheet = Nothing
Set ExcelWorkbook = Nothing
Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

I've tried moving the qualifications, using .quit, etc., but still end up with that one excel.exe process in task mananger.  The issue is definitally in the for each loop.  If I close before then, it's good.

Comment: does the excel file successfully open?  What's the value of ExcelWorkbook.worksheets.count?

Comment: you don't need the outer With ExcelApp loop.

Comment: Yes it opens.  The value is 8.

Comment: I just threw the extra outer loop in there trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing the excel workbook, but not excel itself. What if you tried something like

```
ExcelApp.Close
```

Comment: does 'ExcelApp.Quit' do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
i = i + 1
```

to this:

```
ExcelWorkSheet.Activate
```

Comment: Nope, still has the instance running.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA even though you set your objects to `Nothing`, the resources aren't truely released until the variables go out of scope, and in this case this is the end of your sub/function. You can call this code from inside another sub or function and as long as the excel app is locally declared when it goes out of scope it will be removed from the running processes.

There's an entry in [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/04/28/122259.aspx) that explains the reasons why.

Comment: Nope, still has the instance running.

Comment: This seems unusual. Do you have any other code inside the loop? does it do that with just `i = i + i` in it?

Comment: On my actual program I have a lot of code.  However, trying to figure out the issue I'm running only the above.

Comment: another thing to try.. Add the false flag (saveChanges) after you close the workbook `ExcelWorkbook.Close False`. Also, has this problem persisted across reboots?

Comment: I just tested this in MSword, (but with the excel related bits defined as `Object`) less than a second after the sub exited the EXCEL process disappeared from the task manager.

Comment: I need it to exit before the sub ends though (as it should).  Halt your code at the End Sub and see if it's still there.

Comment: @user3022724 I updated my answer. I misunderstood your question, I originally thought that Excel was still present after it had gone out of scope.